# Notes app: search inside scanned document

Tags: search, scanning, image-capture, ocr

How do I get to the detailed search result within a camera scanned document in the Notes app?

If I create a note on my iPhone, and use the camera to "scan" a document, it looks like the content of the document is searchable by the global search in the Notes app on my Mac and iPhone. But how do I find the exact location within that document? There appears to be no highlight of the search result, nor any way to search within that document.

Is there an obvious trick that I am missing? Even if I open the attached document in a new window, there is no search interface at all.

I am using macOS Ventura and iOS 16.1.1

Comment: I think the answer is not directly possible. Workarounds involve: Taking the image into an OCR app (e.g. PDFPen/Nitro), doing the OCR, copying the text and pasting into Notes.  Not what you want, I know. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to find the position of a text in scanned images, but it doesn't involve the Notes app. Instead, go to the Home screen on your iPhone and pull down / swipe down to bring up the search screen.

[image: screenshot of iPhone search screen]

Type in your search term – hits from other apps, incl. photos found in apps come up. (Some image results redacted here)

[image: screenshot of searching for a word]

Select "Show More >" on the right, a more detailed screen with the photos from the respective app is shown. The icon in the lower right of each image preview shows that the text you searched for has been recognised in this image.

[image: screenshot of photos from apps]

Select an image.

[image: screenshot of a selected image with the search text highlighted]

Close up of the found text within the image.

[image: screenshot of an image detail with the found text]

However, to my knowledge there is no seeking of found text in scanned images **in the Notes app**. Nevertheless, you can scan text into a note when you capture the image. The process is described [here](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/guide/iphone/iph653f28965/ios).

How to scan text into a note

1. In a note, tap the Camera button, then tap Scan Text.
   [image: Scan Text]
2. Position iPhone so that the text appears within the camera frame. Once the yellow frame appears around detected text, it gets added to the note. You can also tap a different area of text for the yellow frame to appear around that.
   [image: Tap to scan]
3. You can then either tap "Insert" to add that text to the note and close the camera, or tap the Live Text button. The latter option allows you to select specific text within the detected text frame. Then tap "Insert" to insert that text to the note.

I agree that this isn't perfect when you need to scan a lot of text. Given your problem I assume you'd have taken a number of photos with text. To pinpoint where a searched and found text is however, it needs to be in text form not text in an image.

If you already have a number of photos with text in them, you can hit the Live Text button and copy that text, then paste it either below all these photos, or in a separate note, which you can then search over. Again, not ideal. I understand it would've been much better if photos with scanned text would be treated just like text, but Apple hasn't implemented that function (yet).

Maybe you will need an external app to master that. While I haven't tested this, it seems that [Photos Search](https://apps.apple.com/au/app/photos-search/id1523063832) does what you're looking for. The preview video shows a contextual menu entry "Show Text", which looks like it does what you're looking for:

[image: Show Text]

Comment: thank you for this very detailed answer. however I talk about a a different function. In your first screenshot I've used the second option called "Scan Documents" this will allow you to capture a document as a note. The text on the document is then somehow indexed for search in the notes app and I try to find the text location within such scanned document

Comment: Yes, I thought you would have used the "Scan Documents" option, but while it's good to capture the original document, it doesn't allow you to pinpoint (or located) text that you searched for. For that, you need to use the "Scan Text" option or highlight the text in the scanned document and then paste it as text in the note. It's not ideal, but the only way I see to locate text.